# VBA, Delimit excel files by "|" upon opening

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that opens .txt files in excel, is there a way to delimit them upon opening? Note: Multiple files are open, so something like active workbooks split by "|", not sure how to split.  UserInput is in my dictionary and is the file picker.

This is what I currently have:

```
Sub Rec()


    Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer



     ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With



'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If


For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary



On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler


Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing



' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Record a macro while using `Data>>From Text` to open one of the pipe-delimited files.  That will give you some idea of how to handle this.

Comment: Its able to work on the first file, any ideas on how to loop it through both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you are using Excel 2010 or later the following should work (the primary change is to your WorkBooks.Open statement):

```
Sub Rec()
    Dim fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer

    ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'get user input for files to search
    Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
    If errCheck Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary

        On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=filenames(Key), _
                           DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                           Other:=True, _
                           OtherChar:="|"
        On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

    Next 'End of the fileNames loop
    Set fileNames = Nothing

    ' Reset system settings
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

As Workbooks.OpenText will display an error message if it can't open the file, you can probably get rid of your error handler entirely (I have done so in the edited version above), or you could suppress OpenText's automatic error message by setting Application.DisplayAlerts to False, and then continue to have your own error handler.  (It depends on what you want to do if the file doesn't exist.)

Comment: Oops - I misread [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) - it also works in 2010

Comment: I get it in red text in vba editor, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's me being stupid and not actually testing things before posting them - it needs brackets around the parameters

Comment: I get a compile error on Open text . `Expected function or variable`

Comment: That's me being stupid again.  (You would have thought that I would have learned after the last time!!)

Comment: having trouble getting this to work. I got rid of Set wb = nothing, added your code, getting the variable not set, Shouldnt I set wb =  your code?

Comment: @Jonnyboi I meant for you to remove the entire line saying "Set wb = Nothing".  As you will no longer be setting wb to anything, you can remove all references to it.  I'll update my answer to show the complete rewrite of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Split it and loop through it

```
Sub Break_String()  
Dim WrdArray() As String  
Dim text_string As String  
text_string = "A|B|C|D"  
WrdArray() = Split(text_string, "|")  
For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)  
  strg = strg & vbNewLine & "Part No. " & i & " - " & WrdArray(i)  
Next i  
MsgBox strg  
End Sub
```

Comment: where do I alter this to split by character? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your update, do I have to input the text between the "|" ? Or will it just delimit

Comment: I assume you are getting a list of files delimited. `file1.txt|file2.txt|file3.txt`  Is this how the list is coming.

Comment: Sorry, the files open via a picker. Now when they open I want to loop through and delimit the first column by "|" .  I want to make columns from the one column.

Comment: The picker will be returning the names in an array.  You will have to loop through that and get them out.

Comment: ah, im confused now lol, would you mind altering the original post?